# Changing background color dynamically (Android)

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private BufferedReader br;
private Socket s;
private View v,v1;
private RelativeLayout rl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        s = new Socket("192.168.1.36",50000);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    color();
}


private void color(){

    rl = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.rellay);
    while(true){
        try{

            String received = br.readLine();
            if(received != null){
            //  System.out.println(received);
            String[] color = received.split(",");
                            setColor(color);

            }
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
private void setColor(String[] color){
    rl = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.rellay);
    int red = Integer.parseInt(color[0]); 
    int green = Integer.parseInt(color[1]);
    int blue = Integer.parseInt(color[2]);
    int a = Integer.parseInt(color[3]);
    rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(a, red, green, blue));
```

What I want to do is receive 4 values separated by commas (this works), and I want the values in the range 0-255 to be the RGB color.

I want to change the background of the android activity. I can change the color once, from the onCreate method, but when I try to change it further times I get the default white screen. The values never exceed 255.

How can this be done? Thanks!!

Comment: This is really really badly architected and you should also not be doing network activity on the main thread. There is also no error catching so it's only a matter of time. If you want some help post your log cat so we can see what's going wrong. Also having your co-workers upvote your bad questions as you post them isn't in the spirit of SO.

Comment: I know it may not have a really good structure. I only want to know how to change the background color of the activity every time the application receives the values from the socket. There are no exceptions going on, it just doesn't change the color. (It remains white). I'm a beginner in Android and I have tried many other methods I founs to change the color, but any of them worked.

Comment: @PereGarauBurguera Put a `Log.d("tag", color.toString())` to your `setColor` function and check the input argument. the alpha must be greater then `0` to be visible `alpha == opacity != transparency`

Comment: Yes the value received is greater than 0. If I do rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(Some Color)); in my OnCreate method once I get the color changed, if I don't execute the color() function. However, if I execute the color() function I get a white screen (and I'm receiving visible colors) I get a white screen.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the alpha value != 0.
The alpha value represent the transparency of the color so 0 is fully transparent.
try to start with fixed values, like:

```
rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));
```

and make sure it works.
after that, pull your values from the server and parse them into a color.

BTW, Listen to  Nick Cardoso comments, It's a bad user experience to feel the network latency.

Comment: See my comment above. I have alpha values greater than 0